# Why my code doesn't work correctly by sometimes returning true instead of false?

Tags: javascript, boolean

This is my code:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 1]) {
      counter += 1;
    } else if (sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i - 1]) {
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  if (counter <= 1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]));

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 5, 5, 5]));

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]));
```

This code's job is to:

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

Example

For `sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be

```
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;
```

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For `sequence = [1, 3, 2]`, the output should be

```
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.
```

You can remove `3` from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 2]`. Alternately, you can remove `2` to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 3]`.

But it doesn't work correctly even after a bunch of edits. Currently, these are the arrays that the code doesn't work correctly on:

- `[1, 3, 2, 1]` It returns true instead of false.
- `[1, 2, 5, 5, 5]` It returns true instead of false.
- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]` It returns false instead of true.

I'm editing this code long time ago, every time I add something/edit something, a problem gets fixed but another problem gets messed up and it keeps like that.

EDIT: Please tell me why it doesn't work, don't give me the right code please.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Very related: [question about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642034/how-can-i-make-this-faster-by-removing-one-element-from-an-array-check-if-arra) - that doesn't explain the bug in the code though, just should be an intersting read.

Comment: His code was different though. He used splice to remove the item and see if it is false or true but it doesn't work since splice changes the content of the array originally and so that can mess stuff up. My code uses counter and if statements to see if there are more than 1 decreasing number or not in an array. And returns true or false based on that.

Comment: Your code "doesn't work" because you don't have the right algorithm. Not working is the natural state of a program, until you write code to make it work. You haven't done so.

Comment: melpomene, you mean the whole logic or that it just needs some tweaks? Because I'm pretty sure that this is the right logic. It just needs some tweaks.

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm and why it should work in plain English?

Comment: The algorithm is very straight. You find 2 decreasing elements or more, increase counter to more than 1 and return false. You find only 1 decreasing element, increase counter to 1 only and return true. You find an element that is decreasing and increasing in its own pace, then increase counter to more than 1 and return false, you find an element that is decreasing AND the element next and element before are equal, you increase counter to more than 1 and return false. This is what the algorithm should be. Also, I have seen a lot of people do it and it succeeded as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "*an element that is decreasing and increasing in its own pace*"? Your description is kind of a mess. What counter are you talking about? Why bother incrementing a counter if the next step is to return?

Comment: I mean an element that decreases like 1,2,3,1 then increases to 2,3 again to be something like this overall: 1,2,3,1,2,3. This is an array that should return false because [i-1] > [i] and [i-1] > [i+1], also it shouldn't return a boolean. Because the function can't exactly know if there are more decreasing element or no. By incrementing a counter, the function can know if there are 2 or more decreasing elements and returns false.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your algorithm, because it clearly says "*You find 2 decreasing elements [...], increase counter [...] and return false*".

Comment: Believe me. I edited it a lot of times. I tried || and else if()...etc, nothing works. Maybe like you said, the whole algorithm is wrong?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm still waiting for a clear description of the algorithm you're trying to implement, because it's not at all clear from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function increasingSequence(sequence,i){
  sequence = Array.prototype.slice.call(sequence);
  sequence.splice(i,1)
  var len = sequence.length;
  for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
    if(sequence[i]>=sequence[i+1])return false;
   }
  return true;
}

function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var len = sequence.length;
  for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
    if(sequence[i]>=sequence[i+1]){
      return increasingSequence(sequence,i)||increasingSequence(sequence,i+1)
     }
   }
   return true;
}
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,3]));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1,3,2]));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,3,3,2]));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It's O(n) , the worst situation is O(2n) ,best situation is O(n)

Comment: @ASDFGerte That doesn't sound right. I see at most one call to `increasingSequence`.

Comment: True - my bad, i did not read the code well enough and my brain jumped to all the O(n²) solutions which are very similar in nature. Btw, the downvote is not from me anyways.

Comment: Sadly, this fails for e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 1]`.

Comment: oh,It's my bad,sequence.splice(i,1) ==>sequence.splice(i+1,1),oh ,It 's not right. I need thinking about it

Comment: Please add an explanation, not just code. The OP specifically asked for an explanation, and code-only answers tend to not be useful to other readers and therefore attract downvotes.

Comment: The code works but can you please explain the code to me? I want to learn more than knowing the right code.

Comment: @Boy pro   My idea is simple. If there is a conflict when sequence[i]>=sequence[i+1]   . i need to resolve the confilct. if i delete a element (the confilct element sequence[i] or sequence[i+1]) ,it's a   increasingSequence , the question is resolve.  else  it's not a almostIncreasingSequence

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make [this, from a now deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097657/4099593), as the right answer:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    return sequence.map((_, index) => [...sequence.slice(0, index), ...sequence.slice(index + 1)])
        .some(arr => arr.every((value, index) => index === 0 || value > arr[index - 1]));
}
```

Comment: The issue with above solution is it being O(n²). Peng's code is O(n) and should, after latest edits, also work. Yes, the person who posted above code deleted his answer (currently, undelete is an option aswell...). PS: this is not an answer, perhaps an edit would be preferrable.

Comment: Actually the solution above doesn't have an issue. It passed all the tests without a timeout. But yes, Peng's code works. So I think I will choose him as the right answer. Again, thank you all for your help! Though I didn't understand a lot from these codes, I think by the time goes, I will be able to.

Comment: Peng's solution solved the unit tests i used approximately 200 times faster (!). Note that order issues appear on larger inputs - above solution will have trouble on large inputs which Peng's code would still solve within milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. This code challenge seems to make people frequently produce faulty code (as seen here and also on the question i linked, i also made a mistake when first solving it. Presumably because it looks very easy but has several pitfalls, people hurry too much). The resulting storm of people posting their attempts made the original question go into the background.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to solve it for the whole day. The issue is that this code becomes complicated once your ideas get failed by the results of tests. But oh my god if it's not hard. It looks easy but once you get in, new issues appear. Anyway, for now I will just "skip" understanding it and I will back to it some time later. Again, thank you all! I'm really glad to know that I'm not the only one who suffered through this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way is to go through the sequence only once. This code remembers the previous number and checks if the current one is higher. If it is lower or equal, then it marks the higher number as the mistake, so the next number can be higher again.

```js
function isIncreasingWithMistakes(sequence) {
  prev = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  var mistakeCounter = 0;
  for (var number of sequence) {
    if (prev < number) {
      // The good case
      prev = number
    }
    else {
      // Found a mistake
      mistakeCounter += 1
      prev = Math.min(prev, number)  // Eliminate the higher number
    }

    // Stop immediately when there are too many mistakes
    if (1 < mistakeCounter) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

// These should be true
console.log(isIncreasingWithMistakes([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]))
console.log(isIncreasingWithMistakes([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

// These should be false
console.log(isIncreasingWithMistakes([1, 3, 2, 1]))
console.log(isIncreasingWithMistakes([1, 2, 5, 5, 5]))
console.log(isIncreasingWithMistakes([1,2,3,4,3,6,1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work

```js
 function _doAlmostIncreasingSequence(_seq, recheck) {
    var warning = 0;
    var _control = _seq[0] - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < _seq.length; i++) {
      var _test = _seq[i];
      if (_test <= _control) {
        if (recheck) {
          var test1 = _seq.slice(0);
          var test2 = _seq.slice(0);
          test1.splice(i, 1);
          test2.splice(i - 1, 1);
          return _doAlmostIncreasingSequence(test1) || _doAlmostIncreasingSequence(test2);
        }
        return false;
      }
      _control = _test;
    }
    return true;
}
function almostIncreasingSequence(_seq) {
    return _doAlmostIncreasingSequence(_seq, 1);
}
console.log("TRUE :", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log("TRUE :", almostIncreasingSequence([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log("TRUE :", almostIncreasingSequence([4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log("FALSE :", almostIncreasingSequence([4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]));
console.log("TRUE :", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 12]));
console.log("FALSE :", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log("FALSE :", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log("TRUE :", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Boypro can you give an example where it does not work?

Comment: `[4,5,6,1,2,3]`

Comment: `[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @ASDFGerte - another edit, hope this works in all cases (thanks for the challenge)